# java generated parallel IntStream(and other stream) issues

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-stream, generator, generate

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
    IntStream
            .generate(
                    () -> {
                        int item = i.incrementAndGet();
                        System.out.println("[generator]： "
                                + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + ", item:" + item);
                        return item;
                    })
            .limit(5)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(
                    item -> {
                        System.out.println("[consumer]: "
                                + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + ", item:" + item);
                    });
}
```

> **In my mind the generator should call 5(limit) times and the consumer should executing in multiple thread,but the generator called 512 times
>   and the consumer executing in same thread, anyone can explain me its a
>   bug or I'm not use correct way?**
>
> outputs: [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:3
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:5 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:6 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:7 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:8 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:9 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:10 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:4 [generator]： main, item:2
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:1 [generator]：
>   main, item:13 [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:12
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:11 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:16 [generator]： main, item:15
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:14 [generator]：
>   main, item:19 [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:18
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:17 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:22 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:24 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:25 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:26 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:27 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:28 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:29 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:30 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:31 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:32 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:33 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:34 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:35 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:36 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:37 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:38 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:39 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:40 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:41 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:42 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:43 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:44 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:45 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:46 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:47 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:48 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:49 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:50 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:51 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:52 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:53 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:54 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:55 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:56 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:57 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:58 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:59 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:60 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:61 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:62 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:63 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:64 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:65 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:66 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:67 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:68 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:69 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:70 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:71 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:72 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:73 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:74 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:75 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:76 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:77 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:78 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:79 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:80 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:81 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:82 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:83 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:84 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:85 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:86 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:87 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:88 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:89 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:90 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:91 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:92 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:93 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:94 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:95 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:96 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:97 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:98 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:99 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:100 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:101 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:102 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:103 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:104 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:105 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:106 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:107 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:108 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:109 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:110 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:111 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:112 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:113 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:114 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:115 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:116 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:117 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:118 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:119 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:120 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:121 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:122 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:123 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:124 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:125 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:126 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:127 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:128 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:129 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:130 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:131 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:132 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:133 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:134 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:135 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:136 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:137 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:138 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:139 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:140 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:141 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:142 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:143 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:144 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:145 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:146
>   **[consumer]: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:4 [consumer]: ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:12 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:16 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:18 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:22** [generator]： main, item:21
>   [generator]： main, item:147 [generator]： main, item:148 [generator]：
>   main, item:149 [generator]： main, item:150 [generator]： main, item:151
>   [generator]： main, item:152 [generator]： main, item:153 [generator]：
>   main, item:154 [generator]： main, item:155 [generator]： main, item:156
>   [generator]： main, item:157 [generator]： main, item:158 [generator]：
>   main, item:159 [generator]： main, item:160 [generator]： main, item:161
>   [generator]： main, item:162 [generator]： main, item:163 [generator]：
>   main, item:164 [generator]： main, item:165 [generator]： main, item:166
>   [generator]： main, item:167 [generator]： main, item:168 [generator]：
>   main, item:169 [generator]： main, item:170 [generator]： main, item:171
>   [generator]： main, item:172 [generator]： main, item:173 [generator]：
>   main, item:174 [generator]： main, item:175 [generator]： main, item:176
>   [generator]： main, item:177 [generator]： main, item:178 [generator]：
>   main, item:179 [generator]： main, item:180 [generator]： main, item:181
>   [generator]： main, item:182 [generator]： main, item:183 [generator]：
>   main, item:184 [generator]： main, item:185 [generator]： main, item:186
>   [generator]： main, item:187 [generator]： main, item:188 [generator]：
>   main, item:189 [generator]： main, item:190 [generator]： main, item:191
>   [generator]： main, item:192 [generator]： main, item:193 [generator]：
>   main, item:194 [generator]： main, item:195 [generator]： main, item:196
>   [generator]： main, item:197 [generator]： main, item:198 [generator]：
>   main, item:199 [generator]： main, item:200 [generator]： main, item:201
>   [generator]： main, item:202 [generator]： main, item:203 [generator]：
>   main, item:204 [generator]： main, item:205 [generator]： main, item:206
>   [generator]： main, item:207 [generator]： main, item:208 [generator]：
>   main, item:209 [generator]： main, item:210 [generator]： main, item:211
>   [generator]： main, item:212 [generator]： main, item:213 [generator]：
>   main, item:214 [generator]： main, item:215 [generator]： main, item:216
>   [generator]： main, item:217 [generator]： main, item:218 [generator]：
>   main, item:219 [generator]： main, item:220 [generator]： main, item:221
>   [generator]： main, item:222 [generator]： main, item:223 [generator]：
>   main, item:224 [generator]： main, item:225 [generator]： main, item:226
>   [generator]： main, item:227 [generator]： main, item:228 [generator]：
>   main, item:229 [generator]： main, item:230 [generator]： main, item:231
>   [generator]： main, item:232 [generator]： main, item:233 [generator]：
>   main, item:234 [generator]： main, item:235 [generator]： main, item:236
>   [generator]： main, item:237 [generator]： main, item:238 [generator]：
>   main, item:239 [generator]： main, item:240 [generator]： main, item:241
>   [generator]： main, item:242 [generator]： main, item:243 [generator]：
>   main, item:244 [generator]： main, item:245 [generator]： main, item:246
>   [generator]： main, item:247 [generator]： main, item:248 [generator]：
>   main, item:249 [generator]： main, item:250 [generator]： main, item:251
>   [generator]： main, item:252 [generator]： main, item:253 [generator]：
>   main, item:254 [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:20
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:256 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:257 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:258 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:259 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:260 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:261 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:262 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:263 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:264 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:265 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:266 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:267 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:268 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:269 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:270 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:271 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:272 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:273 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:274 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:275 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:276 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:277 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:278 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:279 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:280 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:281 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:282 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:283 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:284 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:285 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:286 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:287 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:288 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:289 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:290 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:291 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:292 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:293 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:294 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:295 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:296 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:297 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:298 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:299 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:300 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:301 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:302 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:303 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:304 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:305 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:306 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:307 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:308 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:309 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:310 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:311 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:312 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:313 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:314 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:315 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:316 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:317 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:318 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:319 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:320 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:321 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:322 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:323 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:324 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:325 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:326 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:327 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:328 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:329 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:330 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:331 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:332 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:333 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:334 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:335 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:336 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:337 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:338 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:339 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:340 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:341 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:342 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:343 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:344 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:345 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:346 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:347 [generator]： main, item:255
>   [generator]： main, item:349 [generator]： main, item:350 [generator]：
>   main, item:351 [generator]： main, item:352 [generator]： main, item:353
>   [generator]： main, item:354 [generator]： main, item:355 [generator]：
>   main, item:356 [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:23
>   [generator]： main, item:357 [generator]： main, item:359 [generator]：
>   main, item:360 [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:348
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:362 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:363 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:364 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:365 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:366 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:367 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:368 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:369 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:370 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:371 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:372 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:373 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:374 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:375 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:376 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:377 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:378 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:379 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:380 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:381 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:382 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:383 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:384 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:385 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:386 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:387 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:388 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:389 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:390 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:391 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:392 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1, item:393 [generator]： main, item:361
>   [generator]： main, item:394 [generator]： main, item:395 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:358 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:396 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:397 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:398 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:399 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:400 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:401 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:402 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:403 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:404 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:405 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:406 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:407 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:408 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:409 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:410 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:411 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:412 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:413 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:414 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:415 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:416 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:417 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:418 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:419 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:420 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:421 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:422 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:423 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:424 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:425 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:426 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:427 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:428 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:429 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:430 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:431 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:432 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:433 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:434 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:435 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:436 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:437 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:438 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:439 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:440 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:441 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:442 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:443 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:444 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:445 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:446 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:447 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:448 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:449 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:450 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:451 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:452 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:453 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:454 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:455 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:456 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:457 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:458 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:459 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:460 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:461 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:462 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:463 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:464 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:465 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:466 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:467 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:468 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:469 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:470 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:471 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:472 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:473 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:474 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:475 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:476 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:477 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:478 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:479 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:480 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:481 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:482 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:483 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:484 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:485 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:486 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:487 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:488 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:489 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:490 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:491 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:492 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:493 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:494 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:495 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:496 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:497 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:498 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:499 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:500 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:501 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:502 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:503 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:504 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:505 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:506 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:507 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:508 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:509 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:510 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:511 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3, item:512

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question, but somehow very bad explained. Let's simplify this:

```
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
    IntStream.generate(() -> i.incrementAndGet())
            .parallel()
            .peek(x -> count.incrementAndGet())
            .limit(5)
            .forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Running in java-8, indeed sort of prints `512` on my machine (quite constantly), but the point is that since you are using an *unordered stream* via `generate`, `limit` is free to take whatever part/values it wants; so when you say that in your mind the generator is suppose to be called 5 times only is wrong. It is called any number of times the stream implementation feels like.

At the same time, java-10 indeed runs the generator (`Supplier`) a lot less times (it's not *always* `5`), so probably there was a change internally to faster short-circuit the operations or cancel the tasks that already stared.

Comment: I guess you have asked the same question some time back ;)

Comment: Just realized that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064786/internal-changes-for-limit-and-unordered-stream) had been asked after you wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess, since I'm not that familiar with the technical details:

There is a thread pool. If there is a job to do and an idle thread is available it might be **re**used. Generator and Consumer may use the same threads but it happens independently.

As the [Instream-javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#generate-java.util.function.IntSupplier-) state `IntStream.generate` seems to *Return[..] an infinite sequential unordered stream*, whatever that means. I guess it just stops generating values since because of a garbage collector round that detects that nobody is interested in the results anymore.

Maybe `IntStream.range(0, 5)` is what you are looking for. This also eliminates the need for the atomic integer and the function side effects.

Comment: IntStream.range(0, 5) not I want, because I need use generator to get data from a datasource, and every time the generator I called, it should return next record, so when it limit 5, it should return first 5 records, but in fact it get more then 5 records, and only consume 5 records, another records are missing

Comment: How does your datasource access look like?

Comment: like consume 100 messages from queue

Answer (score 0):

After executing your code a number of times, this is what I have observed:

- `i.incrementAndGet()` is executed a random number of times. Here are some counts: 384, 256, 128, 768, 640, 896, 1024. But the number of times this method is called is always divisible by 8. There are 8 threads involved.
- The `forEach` always picks one thread at random (it can be the main thread or another ForkJoin pool thread) and prints its items out. No matter what you do, it is ordered.

I think the API is behaving correctly, since `IntStream.generate` is more suited to generate random numbers and effectively this is what it is doing. It's Javadoc description is:

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is
>   generated by the provided {@code IntSupplier}.  This is suitable for
>   generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

This is the test I have used to check the behaviour:

```
IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(c -> {
    AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
    IntStream
            .generate(
                    () -> {
                        int item = i.incrementAndGet();
//                            System.out.println("[generator]： "
//                                    + Thread.currentThread().getName()
//                                    + ", item:" + item);
                        return item;
                    })
            .limit(5)
            .parallel()
            .forEach(
                    item -> {
                        System.out.println("[consumer]: "
                                + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                + ", item:" + item);
                    });
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(i.intValue() % 8);
});
```

My suggestion would be to run your code multiple times always to get a better picture of what is going on. It is not entirely true that the generator is called 512 times.

Comment: 1. parallel Stream should work in multiple threads when use forEach, but only have one thread to processing, I think its a bug

Comment: @Max And it uses multiple threads. The printout in the `foreEach` method sometimes is written by the main thread and sometimes not. Try running my test code on your machine.

Comment: add sorted: limit(5).sorted().parallel() then can uses multiple threads, but we have this case: use generate to get record(message) from a data source, every time the generator we called, will return next record, it works fine when in non-parallel mode, but parallel mode is a better choice, it will have good performance(but it not works when we use parallel)

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks all, I checked in java 10.0.1:
>   1. The code will works in multiple threads(so java 8 should a bug work in single thread, and fixed in 10.0.1)
>   2. generator called 9 times(test in Intellj, its random), it's because have multiple threads fetch the items, and another thread to processing, and the fetch data threads not do the limit
>
> [generator]： main, item:1 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:3 [consumer]: main, item:1
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4, item:2 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13, item:6 [generator]： main, item:5
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11, item:4 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2, item:3 [consumer]: main, item:5
>   [generator]： ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-6, item:9 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13, item:6 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15, item:8 [consumer]:
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4, item:2 [generator]：
>   ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9, item:7