# CompletableFuture stream created from iterator is not lazily evaluated

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future, spliterator

I'm struggling a bit with how and when completable futures are completed. I have created this test case:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class StreamOfCompletableFuturesTest {
    @Test
    public void testList() {
        completeFirstTwoElements(
                Stream.of("list one", "list two", "list three", "list four", "list five")
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void testIterator() {
        Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList("iterator one", "iterator two", "iterator three", "iterator four", "iterator five").iterator();

        completeFirstTwoElements(
            StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
        );
    }

    private void completeFirstTwoElements(Stream<String> stream) {
        stream
                .map(this::cf)
                .limit(2)
                .parallel()
                .forEach(cf -> {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(cf.get());
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> cf(String result) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            System.out.println("Running " + result);
            return result;
        });
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Running list one
Running list two
list two
list one
Running iterator one
Running iterator two
Running iterator three
Running iterator four
Running iterator five
iterator two
iterator one
```

The `testList` method works as expected. The `CompletableFuture`'s are only evaluated at the very end, so after the limit method has only kept the first two items.

However, the `testIterator` method is unexpected. All `CompletableFuture`'s are completed and the limiting is only done afterwards.

If I remove the `parallel()` method from the stream it works as expected. However, the processing (the `forEach()`) should be done in parallel because in my full program it is a long-running method.

Can any one explain why this is happening?

It looks like this depends on the Java version, so I'm on 1.8:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Works fine with `java 9.0.4 (build 9.0.4+11)` on Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: and yes, I confirm it gives the incorrect result with the `jdk-1.8.0_152`

Comment: @MarkoPacak thanks for figuring out that this is Java version related. I hadn't even thought of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parallelism applies to the whole pipeline, so you cannot really control what will be executed before the `limit()` is applied in a parallel `Stream`. The only guarantee is that what's after the `limit()` will only be executed on the retained elements.

The difference between the two is probably due to some implementation details or other `Stream` characteristics. In fact, you can easily invert the behavior by playing on the `SIZED` characteristic. It seems when the `Stream` has a known size, only 2 elements are processed.

So for example, applying a simple `filter()` will lose the size of the list version:

```
completeFirstTwoElements(
        Stream.of("list one", "list two", "list three", "list four", "list five").filter(a -> true)
);
```

outputs for example:

```
Running list one
Running list five
Running list two
Running list three
list one
list two
```

And not using the *unknown size* version of `Spliterator.spliterator()` "fixes" the behavior:

```
Iterator<String> iterator = Arrays.asList("iterator one", "iterator two", "iterator three", "iterator four", "iterator five").iterator();

completeFirstTwoElements(
        StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliterator(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED, 5), false)
);
```

Output:

```
Running iterator two
Running iterator one
iterator one
iterator two
```

Comment: Interestingly, Java 9 treats “unknown size” differently to streams with an estimate, so combining the fix `Spliterators.spliterator(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED, 5)` with the subsequent `a -> true` filter will perform worse than `Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator, Spliterator.ORDERED)`, with or without filter. Anyway, congratulations for being 10s faster then me.

Answer (score 4):

Your statement “all `CompletableFuture`s are completed” is equivalent to “all `CompletableFuture`s are created”, as once `supplyAsync` has been executed, the evaluation of the supplier has been scheduled, regardless of whether someone will eventually invoke `get` or not.

So what you perceive here, is the evaluation of the function passed to `map`, even if the subsequent processing will not consume the result. This is a valid behavior; the function may get evaluated for more elements than necessary, in an arbitrary order or even concurrently, as long as the Stream will use the right results afterwards, in respect to the limit and encounter order.

Now, whether evaluating more elements than necessary will happen and how many excess elements are processed, is an implementation detail and the implementation has changed, as discussed in “[Internal changes for limit and unordered stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50064786/2711488)”. While that Q&A is about unordered streams, it’s plausible that similar improvements were made for ordered streams.

The takeaway is that you should not assume that the functions are only evaluated for the minimum number of required elements. Doing so would reduce the efficiency of parallel processing. This still applies, even when Java 9 improved the parallel `limit` operation. A simple change may re‑intro­duce the evaluation of more elements:

```
private void completeFirstTwoElements(Stream<String> stream) {
    stream.map(this::cf)
          .filter(x -> true)
          .limit(2)
          .parallel()
          .forEach(cf -> System.out.println(cf.join()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response (you too @didier-l). One more question: is there a way to cancel the scheduling? In my full program, what happens in the supplyAsync call takes a long time and will stop the program from terminating until all supplyAsyncs are fully executed. This is not needed, I only want the first 10.
(BTW I have the feeling I need to rethink the architecture of my program as CompletableFuture does not seem to match very well with what I want to do)

Comment: Cancellation of a `CompletableFuture` will not interrupt an already ongoing evaluation, it may only prevent the evaluations of functions which have not started yet at the time of cancellation. However, this does not prevent your application from terminating. Your application will only get blocked if you call `get` or `join()` on the associated future. If you have cancelled the future, you won’t even get blocked on `get` or `join()` though there might still be an ongoing background evaluation whose result won’t be used afterwards. These background evaluations do not prevent the JVM termination.

Comment: Thanks again, the problem was that I was chaining additional operations with `thenApply` and these were waiting for all the `supplyAsync` calls to be finished. This is tricky stuff, even though the API looks fairly simple.